# Error starting the server JBoss EAP 7.1 while playing with helloworld-rs quickstart

Tags: jboss-eap-7, jboss-developer-studio

I know this is old but while I was doing this I get the following error when starting the server in step 2 of this quickstart ( Install, Configure and Verify )
https://developers.redhat.com/products/devstudio/hello-world/

**Error**

< terminated > Red Hat JBoss EAP 7.1 [JBoss Application Server Startup Configuration] C:\Dev\Java\32_bits\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\javaw.exe
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 1335296KB object heap

I've followed the steps indicated in the quickstart but I can't make it work

I tried modifying the size of the memory in host.xml and domain.xml files under EAP_HOME\domain\configuration but it didn't work

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks

System:
Windows 10 Home SL
8 GB RAM
Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio 11.3.0.GA
JDK 1.8.0_172

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using 32bit JDK; theoretically, 32-bit processes can address up to 4 Gigabytes and 64-bit processes can address up to 16ExaBytes. Typically 64-bit processes don't need to worry about the limit as it is very high.

You can try decrease JVM process size by decreasing the heap or perm gen size.